# Installation of RHEL and softwares on multiple machines

Tags: system-installation, kickstart, replication

In our organization, we have 15 new systems each with same hardware.

I need to setup all the machines with RHEL 6.0 in it, multiple software, and lot of basic configuration. I don't have any problem in installing it one-by-one but it obviously takes too much time.

Is there any method/technology/script to replicate this to other machines? (I know only kickstart, but that is used only for installation of RHEL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a `kickstart` server and a `kickstart` configuration file that specifies your disk layout, packages to be installed and a `%post` section.  In this later section you can deploy any number of scripts (shell, Perl, etc.) from your `kickstart` server that will be executed to customize your basic configuration.

The time you invest setting up a `kickstart` server will be well worth the effort.  Have a look at the Red Hat documentation [here](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html).

Comment: To the OP: It will be helpful, but not necessary, to have DHCP + PXE Boot so that upon boot, without a valid boot image from disk, they will request a DHCP address from the network, obtain it, find a "pointer" to where it can download code from which it will then boot into a redhat install image. The install image in turn uses the kickstart file you have configured for that node.

Answer (score 1):

There is the redhat satellite server, or its opensource version spacewalk, which could help you with managing these systems.

http://spacewalk.redhat.com